# How to "change" folder name (and block original path) using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

i.e. I have (actual folder path):

```
example.com/folder1
```

but I want that anyone visiting that link directly was blocked (not redirecting anywhere, just deny).

Instead, I want that link was only accessed at:

```
example.com/dfjgekbjvrskzcnfvberidurvf
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

At your main root `.htaccess` put the flowing code :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^dfjgekbjvrskzcnfvberidurvf/?(.*)$    /folder1/$1 [L]
```

Then at `.htaccess` file in folder1 directory put this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !dfjgekbjvrskzcnfvberidurvf [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} folder1
RewriteRule ^    - [F,L]
```

Comment: i think it's better to be also checked in php, if url doesnt contain specific words, because they might be bypassed from `.htaccess` restriction with scrumbling, like `fol\der\1` (see more at: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/180920/is-there-any-way-to-bypass-htaccess-path-restriction-in-urls )

Comment: I dont think so, browser will interprets this fol\der\1 as it is